# Anylogic in 3 days. Experiment - CompareRuns

Tags: anylogic

I am working through the Anylogic in 3 days course. I am up to Phase 8. "Comparing model runs with different parameter values", page 93. When I try to run the experiment in step 7. "CompareRuns" is grey. I can still select it, but I do not have the option to click next. I have run the error check and can't find any errors. Can anyone please explain what I might have done wrong, and why I can't click next?

Thanks in advance!
Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong version, likely the free "PLE" (Personal learning edition). However, you need the Professional version instead. Download and install from the AnyLogic website as usual and you can request a free 30-day trial of it, which allows you to use that experiment and all other features.